# Is my question appropriate for stats.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion

Hi folks, I just posted [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11070/request-for-help-modifying-r-simulation-analysis-code). I had trouble deciding whether it would be best posted here or math.stackexchange.com and would appreciate input. Also, how appropriate is it that it's a rather involved request (requiring the successful answerer to understand then modify some simulation/analysis code)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why math.SE? It looks fine to me because this is a clearly exposed problem, with an underlying model, and it appears clearly connected to statistics and *programming for statistics* (hence my +1).

Comment: Agreed.  I'm pretty sure that if it were posted on math.SE it would be migrated here anyway.

Comment: I +1'd it also. It's a good question.